# How fast does a holomorphic function have to decay at $\infty$ in order to satisfy Titchmarsh's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, analytic-functions, integral-transforms

Titchmarch's theorem says that a complex function $f(z)$ is analytic on the (closed) upper half of the complex plane and decays rapidly as $|z| \to \infty$ iff its real and imaginary parts are Hilbert transforms of each other.

But just how fast does in need to decay as $|z| \to \infty$? [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations#Formulation) Wikipedia article says that we only need $\lim \limits_{|z| \to \infty} f(z) = 0$, but [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Titchmarsh%27s_theorem) says that we need that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x + i y)|^2\, dx < K.$$

I believe that this is a stronger requirement. For example, if $f(z) \sim 1/\sqrt{z}$ as $|z| \to \infty$, then the former requirement is met but the latter is violated.